# Did the rich text buttons just disappear?

Tags: support, javascript

I just tried to edit a question (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5468984/edit) and there are no rich text buttons.  They are also hidden when I go to ask a new question.  What happened?

I'm running Firefox 3.6.16 on Server 2008 r2 x64.

Strangely I *can* see the rich text buttons in meta.stackoverflow.

This is what I see:
[image]

Comment: Looks OK for me (IE8, Win7-32 Bit) 8:42UTC. What OS/Browser?

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox 3.6.13 Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your browser's JavaScript cache got corrupted somehow -- did you try hard-refreshing the page?